# Fiddler: Modifying request sent

Tags: security, request, content-type, fiddler

How can I use Fiddler so that I can edit the Content-Type parameter from text/plain to image/jpeg (for example) so I can test a file upload form for vulnerabilities? so that if my site checks for the content-type parameter to be image/jpeg and I upload a text file, content-type will be text/plain then I change it to image/jpeg and the site thinks I'm uploading a .jpeg but really I'm uploading a text file. I wanna try this flaw with my own file upload but I don't know how to edit the request.

Answer (score 2):

This video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bo5kXMAcV0 shows how to tamper requests in general.

Generally speaking, File Upload forms in browsers carry the Content-Type within a multipart form body, so the "header" isn't in the HEADERS tab, it's in the TextView tab which shows the body.

Having said that, what "vulnerability" do you expect you'll find? (Hint: You could probably even do what you're asking without even using Fiddler, simply rename a .JPG file to .TXT)